Looking for references that can teach me some of the fundamentals of computer science (from Peter Norvig's TYPITY page)
I am looking for resources/books/blogs etc from which it can tell me "how long it takes your computer to execute an instruction, fetch a word from memory (with and without a cache miss), read consecutive words from disk, and seek to a new location on disk, send packet US to Europe and back"
The line appears in Peter Norvig's (in)famous page Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years (TYPITY). Though it does answer the questions but I am looking for proper standard books that can help me. Needless to say I am self learning here.
I tried looking for books and the ones that I found from CS Curriculums are 1000 page long and I think people may know better alternatives?
